Trait for Type Level type Equality in stable rust
I've been messing a lot with type level programing in the last few months, but always end up being stuck at the point where I need to add bounds for types that are equal, or not.
So I'm looking for a way to implement a trait that would provide such info:
// type level boolean
trait Boolean {} // type level boolean
struct True;
impl Boolean for True {}
struct False;
impl Boolean for False {}

// the trait I want to implement
trait IsEq<T> {
    // for <T as IsEq<T>> this is True, otherwise this is False
    type Eq: Boolean;
}

This is more complete than a simple IsSame<T> trait :
trait IsSame<T> {}
impl<T> IsSame<T> for T {}

Because it allows to give bounds for types that needs to be different :
fn f<T, U: IsEq<T>>() where <U as IsEq<T>>::Eq: IsFalse { ... } // IsFalse is a trait implemented only for False

So far, I've tried various solutions, all using nightly features:

Specialization allow to provide the default impl to be False, and a specialized impl for equal types, but it's nowhere near stabilization.
generic const exprs, with const type id, allow to check type id equality and go back to the type level world to somehow make this works.
Negative impls should allow this with the IsSame<T> trait, but I've been unable to make it work.

I've seen that the not eq operator != in where clauses have been in discussion for quite a while now (https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1834) but are not planned to be stabilized either any time soon.
I'm running out of options, and this trait would really be useful in a lot of type level programming applications. Is it even possible to implement it in stable Rust ?

It's not currently possible in stable Rust as far as I know, you can use my answer on "How can I ensure that generic argument types are different?" on nightly.

@cafce25 The linked answer shows how to perform such checks, but leaves the type system for const computation. It does not provide a trait that can tell if the types are equal are not, which is a very different use case.

It's fundamentally the same problem. In today's Rust, you can use the type system to prove two types are the same, but not to prove two types are different.
